# Will the str() method in Python work for all types of parameters?

Tags: python

I am trying to raise error messages using the the following line of code:

```
def raise_error(value):
    error = "The value " + str(value) + " does not satisfy the given conditions."
    # Other stuff
```

The value is basically user input obtained from a JSON API, so I am trying to consider all possibilities. Can the method above itself cause an exception in my system if the value given cannot be turned into a string using the `str()` method? If yes, then what are such values that would create the exception?

Comment: All data types valid in a JSON have a `str` representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `str` method will always produce an output, it just might not be meaningful. As noted in the [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) it's calling either `__str__` or `__repr__` depending on what is defined. For all of the basic types like int, float, bool, etc you'll get a nice output. For a custom class though you'll probably get some garbage like:

```
class test:
    pass

print(str(test()))

>>> <__main__.test object at 0x107f2ba20>
```

Now if you define a `__str__` method you'll get something nice like so

```
class test:
    def __str__(self):
        return "A test object"

print(str(test()))
>>> 'A test object'
```

Comment: `<__main__.test object at 0x107f2ba20>` is not garbage. It is what is being defined in the `__repr__` method because `str()` will look for `repr` if `__str__` is not defined.

Comment: @ycx yes, I know this. However, for most people `<__main__.test object at 0x107f2ba20>` is not quite what they're going for when they call `str` on something, especially in an error message.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you don't have to worry about it. The string is generated by the `__str__` or `__repr__` functions, and one or both of these will automatically be created on all new objects and primitives.

---

But technically there are a few scenarios where developers can do dumb stuff.

**Scenario A)** The `__str__` function does not return a string:

```
class Test():
    def __str__(value):
        return

raise_error(Test())
```

This results in the error

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

**Scenario B)** The `__str__` function has the wrong amount of arguments:

```
class Test():
    def __str__():
        return 0

raise_error(Test())
```

This results in the error

```
TypeError: __str__() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Obviously in all three of these scenarios the fault lies with whatever developer was creating the bad `__str__` functions. I think we can all agree that these are not cases your code should have to handle.

Comment: The `AttributeError: __str__` comes from the attempt to delete `__str__`, not from the `str` call.

Comment: @ user2357112 you're right. I've removed that scenario.